# PHP - Show each product from table

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a `products` table where I have products being listed into. I want to create a peice of code that will show the same style but different price, name, description, picture for each product. I have create a peice of code that sort of does this. My code displays only the first in the row. I need to list all of them. My code is :

```
function grabProducts($con) {
    ?>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="col-md-12" id="please_wait">
        <div class="panel panel-warning">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><i>Loading, Please Wait...</i></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#please_wait').fadeOut(7000);
        $('#content_purchase').hide(0).delay(5000).fadeIn("slow");
    });
    </script>
    <?php

    $users = $this->grabUserInfos($con);
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $username = $user[1];
        $email = $user[3];
    }

    $site_config = new site_config();
    $member_config = new member_config();

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM products");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    // See if there are any products in the database
    if ($count > 0) {

        // While loop for each product element
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $picture = $row['picture_location'];
            $price = $row['price'];
            $stock_monitering = $row['stock_monitering'];
            $stock = $row['stock'];
            $new_stock = $stock - 1;

            $url_path = 'http' . (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? '' : 's') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $url_path_naked = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH).'/pizza/products.php';

            $getValidatedCheck_ = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT txn_id, hasValidated, item_name, amount, currency, payment_date FROM payment_logs WHERE userId = '$username' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
            $count_success_payment = mysqli_num_rows($getValidatedCheck_);

            // While loop for our successful payment_logs for each user
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getValidatedCheck_)) {
                $txn_id = $row['txn_id'];
                $validated_check = $row['hasValidated'];    
                $item_name = $row['item_name']; 
                $item_price = $row['amount'];   
                $item_currency = $row['currency'];
                $payment_date = $row['payment_date'];

                $now = strtotime("-10 minutes");

                // If there is not enough stock, show out of stock
                if($stock <= 0) {
                    $display = 'out_of_stock';
                } else if($stock > 0 && $now > strtotime($payment_date)) {
                    $display = 'show_products';
                }

                // If there are no transactions for that user show the products like normal
                if($count_success_payment == 0) {

                    // If they've not already seen the success message, show them it now and update their hasValidated from 0 to 1 so they don't see it again
                    if ($validated_check == '0') {
                        // If stock monitering is on, update our stock to 1 less than we had before the purchase
                        if($stock_monitering == '1') {
                            mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE products SET stock = '$new_stock' WHERE name = '$name'");
                        }
                        $display = 'show_success';
                    }
                }
            }

    switch($display) {
        case "show_products":
        ?>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="content_purchase" style="display: none;">
                <div class="panel panel-danger">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Price: <i>$<?php echo $price; ?></i>
                            <div class="fRight" style="float: right;"><i><?php echo $name; ?></i> Stock
                                (<?php echo $stock; ?>)
                            </div>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <center>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <img src="<?php echo $picture; ?>"
                                 style="width: 85%; height: 100px; margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px; border-radius: 5px; border: 2px solid #ED4949;">
                            <form name="paypal_form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                                <input type="hidden" name="business"
                                       value="<?php $site_config->grabSiteSettings($con, 'paypal_address'); ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
                                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                                <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="username=<? echo $username; ?>&status=<? echo $checkout_status; ?>&product=<? echo $name; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://benzaofficial.com/pizza/includes/checkout.php">
                                <input type="hidden" name="return"
                                       value="<?php $site_config->grabSiteSettings($con, 'site_url'); ?>/pizza/products.php?status=complete">
                                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return"
                                       value="<?php $site_config->grabSiteSettings($con, 'site_url'); ?>/pizza/products.php?status=canceled">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"
                                        style="vertical-align : bottom; margin-bottom: 15px; display: block; width: 85%;">
                                    <i class="fa fa-paypal"></i>aypal
                                </button>
                                <form>
                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        break;
        case "show_success":
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-12" id="content_purchase" style="display: none;">
            <div class="panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><i>PAYMENT SUCCESS!</i></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>You've successfully purchased <i><?php echo $item_name; ?></i> for <i><?php echo $item_price; ?> <i><?php echo $item_currency; ?></i></i> We have emailed you your receipt to <?php echo $email; ?>. You can click <a href="myFiles.php" style="color: white;">here</a> to download your purchased files.<br>Click <a href="<?php echo $url_path; ?>" style="color: white;">here</a> to purchase again.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE payment_logs SET hasValidated = '1' WHERE userId = '$username' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
        break;
        case "no_products":
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-12" id="content_purchase" style="display: none;">
            <div class="panel panel-danger">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><i>Currently No Products For Sale</i></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>There are currently no products up for sale.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        break;
        case "out_of_stock":
        ?>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="content_purchase" style="display: none;">
                <div class="panel panel-danger">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Price: <i>$<?php echo $price; ?></i>
                            <div class="fRight" style="float: right;"><i><?php echo $name; ?></i> Stock
                                (<?php echo $stock; ?>)
                            </div>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <center>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <img src="<?php echo $picture; ?>"
                                 style="width: 85%; height: 100px; margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px; border-radius: 5px; border: 2px solid #ED4949;">
                            <p><i><?php echo $name; ?></i> is currently out of stock. Please come back later and try again.</p>
                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        break;
    }
    }
    } else {
        $display = 'no_products';
    }
 }
```

Comment: I advise you 1) to get acquainted with concepts of PHP template engines, which allow to separate PHP code from HTML. Mixing them together on one page is a bad practice (which was probably a good one in the late 90s) 2) to get acquainted with ORM, which allow to separate business logic from storage (or database) layer. Now you are again mixing raw PHP code, not only with HTML, but also with raw SQL queries. It is also a totally bad practice 3) to get acquanted with PHP frameworks, like Laravel or Phalcon

Comment: @Jacobian This is off topic. It did not answer my question in any way.

Comment: I did not try to answer your question. I just tried to point out, that your code now looks like spaghetti and if you do not follow good practice, in the long run you will end up with something called BBoM.

Comment: @Jacobian I know it's not neat yet. I do that after. I just try to figure the problem out first.

Answer (score 1):

first you need a function dat select all of your products like this one

```
function showproducts($conn,$id){
   $req="SELECT * FROM products ";
   $liste=$conn->query($req);
   return $liste->fetchAll();   
}
```

than you should call this function :

```
$list=$cc->showproducts($cc->conn);
```

and foreach row you can show all columns

```
<?php
   foreach ($list as $l){ ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $l[0] ;?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $l[1] ;?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $l[2] ;?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $l[3] ;?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $l[7] ;?> </td>
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you but is there not a nicer, less code way ?

Comment: Do what @Jacobian said in the comments :)

Comment: i think this is the simplest way , and well organized code . I hope this will helps